# Lagrange densities for spin in different dimensions

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-spin, field-theory, classical-field-theory

I have been looking at the Lagrange equations for spin 0 Klein-Gordon, 1 Proca, and 1/2 Dirac (are there any others?). It seems that from these equations we can find out all of the particles in the universe. But I wonder, how do these equations change if the universe had a different number of dimensions? Say we wanted to know what particles would come about in 2 space 1 time or 4 space 1 time, could we find out from finding Lagrange equations in different dimensions?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/634362/2451

Comment: why do you think the equations should change with dimension (apart from the possible values the indices can take)?

Comment: Well, I would imagine as the dimension changes so too would the particles. It doesn't seem logical to assume particles form and interact in the same way in a different number of dimensions,